# adding user control to toolbox using class Library

Tags: c#, winforms

I have made those steps:

1. Create a new Class Library project.
2. Delete Class1.cs, initially provided with the application.
3. Right click the project in the Solution Explorer and select Add > User Control….
   In the dialog that appears, name the user-control file and click Add.
4. Inside the project, add controls and functionality to the UserControl ( here I added 2 radiobuttons(Bold, Italic) and

a label to change its text using radiobuttons)

1. Build the project. Visual Studio creates a .dll file for the UserControl in the
   output directory (bin/Debug).
2. Create a new Windows application.
3. In the new Windows application, right click the ToolBox and select Choose
   Items…. In the Choose Toolbox Items dialog that appears, click Browse…. Browse
   for the .dll file from the class library created in Steps 1–5. The item will then
   appear in the Choose Toolbox Items dialog. If it is not already
   checked, check this item. Click OK to add the item to the Toolbox. This control
   can now be added to the Form as if it were any other control.

---

when doing the 7th step I got an error

"There are no components in "C:\Users.............\MyDLL.dll that can be placed on the toolbox"

```
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {
        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

what is the reason? please help...

Comment: You need to post some code for us to look at.

Comment: if your windows app is in the same solution as the control it should be automatically inserted(after build ofcourse) if you got the "AutoToolboxPopulate" enabled,else better present some code,maybe toolboxitemattribute issue...

Comment: there is no code. just skip radiobuttons and label in 4th step and there will not be any code. we can just add a simple button without any code, just to be shown later.

Comment: @GeoMan we need the code of your `UserControl`, I doubt that you created it **incorrectly** so that the `ToolBox` couldn't recognize it as a `Control`.

Comment: Have you seen this question: [How can i create a dll of a User Control in a win forms project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14087975/how-can-i-create-a-dll-of-a-user-control-in-a-win-forms-project)